# Using findByCriteria using Session Method in Spring Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public StudentCredential getStudentDetailsByUnameAndPassword(String uname,String password){
        Session session;
        DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentCredential.class);
        detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uname", uname));
        detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
        List<StudentCredential> findByCriteria = (List<StudentCredential>)Hibernate template .findByCriteria(detachedCriteria);
        if(findByCriteria !=null && findByCriteria.size()>0)
        return findByCriteria.get(0);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

I have this code and want to use the findByCriteria of HIbernateTemplate is valdating the data NOw how can I  use Session criteria query or any other method instead of  Hibernate Template to make validation of email and password 
This code helps to save the validate the email and password from the database.

```
package com.infotech.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.infotech.dao.StudentCredentialDao;
import com.infotech.model.Student;
import com.infotech.model.StudentCredential;

@Repository("StudentCredentialDAO")
public class StudentCredentialDaoImpl implements StudentCredentialDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveStudentCred(StudentCredential stuCred) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(stuCred);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
         return true;
    }
```

NOw after saving the code uses Hibernate Template but this doesn't work for me what I can I do to validate the code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public StudentCredential getStudentDetailsByUnameAndPassword(String uname,String password){
            DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria =  DetachedCriteria.forClass(StudentCredential.class);
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("uname", uname));
            detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
            List<StudentCredential> findByCriteria = (List<StudentCredential>)session.getIdentifier(detachedCriteria);
            if(findByCriteria !=null && Hibernate template .size()>0)
            return findByCriteria.get(0);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

This is my full code of DAO file I don't want to use Hibernate Template it is having some problems with Oracle Database. So using session.

Comment: Please provide a code which you attempted already

Comment: I have shown the full code of DAO class